# How to set bold version for single math font file in unicode-math?

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

We can set the bold version for some math fonts which contain separate bold math font files, e.g., XITSMath. But for some math fonts, only one font file, such as STIXMath. In STIXMath, there are also bold symbols. How can we set STIXMath with the bold version, which makes us can use `\boldmath` or `\mathversion{bold}` to get bold symbols?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
% \setmathfont{STIXMath-Regular.otf}
% \setmathfont{STIXMath-Regular.otf}[version=bold]
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular.otf}
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Bold.otf}[version=bold]

\begin{document}

Test $a^3\alpha$

\boldmath \bfseries
Test $a^3\alpha$

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a unicode-math example using (Fake)Bold Stix in my answer in the linked question